# Immediate Resizing of JSplitPane and its Components

Tags: jsplitpane

I have two questions about resizing a JSplitPane.

I would like to force the resizing-process of a JSplitPane to happen while I'm dragging the divider and not when I release the mouse button. How can I implement this?

The second question is about pushing the right side content of a JSplitPane over the frame boundaries. When I'm dragging the divider and for example a JTextField touches the frame border or I'm dragging it over the border it completely disappears. Does anyone know why this happens and how I could prevent this?

I thank you very much for your help!

Comment: For the first issue I didn't really know where to start (to be honest). I thought this might be solved by an "adjustment-listener" or something like that. For the second issue I played around with the properties of the GridBagLayout (such as setting insets, ...). But it didn't really work. If you want I can upload some code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Can help with first question use `JSplitPane.setContinuousLayout(true);`